# Изменение адреса указателя в const методе

Tags: c++, классы, указатели, c++11

Пытаюсь реализовать свой класс map. За основу взял splay-tree. В классе есть указатель на корень дерева Tree *_root, константный метод find(). 
После каждого поиска мне необходимо изменять адрес указателя _root (связано это с концепцией splay деревьев). Попробовал сделать так:

```
class Map {
//....
Tree * mutable _root;
};
```

Но константные методы все равно не могут поменять указатель. Прошу заметить, что необходимо редактировать адрес указателя, а не данные по этому адресу.

Один из способов решения:

```
class Map {
//....
using ptr = Tree *;
mutable ptr _root;
}
```

Но хотелось бы найти решение без использования using/typedef.

Comment: Покажите минимальный пример готовой к компиляции программы, который демонстрирует проблему.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваше объявление указателя

```
Tree * mutable _root;
```

некорректное и не должно компилироваться. Декларатор не может включать в себя спецификатор класса памяти.

Декларатор в виде указателя имеет вид

```
* attribute-specifier-seqopt cv-qualifier-seqopt
```

то есть он допускает использование только квалификаторов.

Поэтому нет никакой необходимости использовать using алиас. Нужно просто правильно записать объявление указателя.

Вы можете менять значение указателя, объявленного с классом памяти `mutable` в константных методах и для константных объектов.

Вот демонстрационная программа

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

struct A
{
    A() : p( nullptr ) {}
    const int * find( const int *a, size_t n, int value ) const
    {
        p = std::find( a, a + n, value );
        if ( p == a + n ) p = nullptr;

        return p;
    }

    mutable const int *p;
};    

int main()
{
    const size_t N = 10;
    int a[N] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

    std::cout << *A().find( a, N, 5 ) << std::endl;

    const A const_a;

    std::cout << *const_a.find( a, N, 9 ) << std::endl;
}
```

Ее вывод на консоль:

```
5
9
```

Comment: @kir55rus Нет, вы не правильно поняли. Спецификатор класса памяти имеет отношение к объявляемому объекту, а не к квалификаторам. Изменять объекты, указываемые указателем вы можете в любом константном методе класса, так как эти объекты не принадлежат самому классу. То есть для этого нет никакой необходимости использовать спецификатор mutable.

Answer (score 0):

Если Ваша задача состоит в том, чтобы корень дерева в любой момент времени мог указывать на какую-то из вершин (кажется, где-то встречался термин "переподвешивание дерева"), может имеет смысл сделать корень дерева двойным указателем?

```
mutable Tree ** _root;
```

Тогда Вы без проблем сможете затолкать туда как раз адрес указателя на какую-то вершину, которая будет считаться корнем в данный момент.